# Where to store security credentials (aka passwords) for special cron jobs?

Tags: passwords, script, cronjob

I want to write a cron job that authenticates for a certain mail account. As there are multiple ways in giving the script those credentails: config file, hardcoded in script, arguments in cronjob call,.. Where do I put those credentials?

(Currently I would favor as giving them the script via arguments as the script is then independent. But is that secure?)

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the credentials into a file that has restricted read access.

<s>Unless your cron tables already have similarly restricted read access.</s> As grawity noted, putting the credentials into the crontab can result in them leaking to logs and/or email. Thus, it should be strongly discouraged and they should be properly protected inside a file.

Comment: Don't put them in the crontab itself; all `cron` jobs are logged in syslog and can sometimes be sent by email.

Comment: @grawity: Ahh, yes as you have written this I remember some weekly cronjob mails.